# Changing UILabel text & location simultaneously not working

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, uilabel

have a button that calls the following code:

```
  algHeaderLabel.frame = CGRect(
    x: algHeaderLabel.frame.origin.x,
    y: algHeaderLabel.frame.origin.y + 400,
    width: algHeaderLabel.frame.size.width,
    height: algHeaderLabel.frame.size.height
  )
  algHeaderLabel.text = "chorus"
```

When I push the button, the text changes to "chorus", but the label does not change position. However, when I push the button a 2nd time, the position then updates.

I also experimented a bit and discovered that if I do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) {
  algHeaderLabel.text = "chorus"
}
```

The location of the label will update, and 3 seconds later the text will update, but will also return the label to it's original location!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is lacking context. Show a bit more code. Make it clear how and when this code is being called. It seems you had a lot more info in the question you deleted. Update this question with some of that info if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
algHeaderLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

This seems to totally solve the problem by turning off Auto Layout for the `UILabel` or any `UIView`.

According to Apple's documentation for `translates​Autoresizing​Mask​Into​Constraints`, it is automatically set to `true` by default for any view created programatically, and `false` for any view created in IB.  This is confusing to me sense I created the label programatically and it has no constraints, so my best guess is that because the `UIViewController` the `UILabel` is a subview to was created in IB, that maybe all of the view controller's subviews are set by default to `false` for this this auto layout property...

In any case, setting `translates​Autoresizing​Mask​Into​Constraints` to `true` for my `UILabel` is what solved this problem for me.